# Trigger Storing wrong information

Tags: sql-server-2008, triggers

Following is my trigger on SQL Server 2008

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[Trigger_UpdateLeadMasters] ON [dbo].[LeadMasters]
FOR UPDATE
AS

DECLARE @CompanyName    nvarchar(50);   
DECLARE @PersonName nvarchar(50);   
DECLARE @Designation    nvarchar(50);   
DECLARE @Number nvarchar(50);   
DECLARE @Number2    nvarchar(50);   
DECLARE @Emailaddress   nvarchar(50);   
DECLARE @Address    nvarchar(MAX);  
DECLARE @Address2   nvarchar(MAX);  
DECLARE @CityName   nvarchar(50);   
DECLARE @State  nvarchar(50);   
DECLARE @PinNumber  nvarchar(50);   
DECLARE @Product    nvarchar(50);   
DECLARE @RemarkNote nvarchar(MAX);
DECLARE @Audit_Action varchar(100);


select @CompanyName=i.CompanyName from inserted i;  
select @PersonName=i.PersonName from inserted i;        
select @Designation=i.Designation from inserted i;
select @Number=i.Number from inserted i;        
select @Number2=i.Number2 from inserted i;      
select @EmailAddress=i.EmailAddress from inserted i;        
select @Address=i.Address from inserted i;      
select @Address2=i.Address2 from inserted i;    
select @CityName=i.CityName from inserted i;        
select @State=i.State from inserted i;      
select @PinNumber=i.PinNumber from inserted i;  
select @Product=i.Product from inserted i;      
select @RemarkNote=i.RemarkNote from inserted i;

IF UPDATE(CompanyName)
set @Audit_Action=' Name Modified or Updated'
IF UPDATE(PersonName)
set @Audit_Action='Person Name Modified or Updated'
IF UPDATE(Designation)
set @Audit_Action='Designation Modified or Updated'
IF UPDATE(Number)
set @Audit_Action='1st Phone Number Modified or Updated'
IF UPDATE(Number2)
set @Audit_Action='2nd Phone Number Modified or Updated'
IF UPDATE(EmailAddress)
set @Audit_Action='Email Address Modified or Updated'
IF UPDATE(Address)
set @Audit_Action='Address Modified or Updated'
IF UPDATE(Address2)
set @Audit_Action='Alternate Address Modified or Updated'
IF UPDATE(CityName)
set @Audit_Action='City Name Modified or Updated'
IF UPDATE(State)
set @Audit_Action='State Modified or Updated'
IF UPDATE(PinNumber)
set @Audit_Action='PinNumber Modified or Updated'
IF UPDATE(Product)
set @Audit_Action='Product Field Modified or Updated'
IF UPDATE(RemarkNote)
set @Audit_Action='Remark Note Modified or Updated'

insert into LoggerLeadMasters(CompanyName,PersonName,Designation,Number,Number2,EmailAddress,Address,Address2,CityName,State,PinNumber,Product,RemarkNote,Audit_Action,Audit_Timestamp)
Values(@CompanyName,@PersonName,@Designation,@Number,@Number2,@EmailAddress,@Address,@Address2,@CityName,@State,@PinNumber,@Product,@RemarkNote,@Audit_Action,GETDATE())
```

But the problem is whenever I modify any field in LeadMasters Table, the trigger goes to line

```
IF UPDATE(RemarkNote)
set @Audit_Action='Remark Note Modified or Updated'
```

and stores wrong information to LoggerLeadMasters.Can anyone help me to fix this issue

Thanks

Comment: Your trigger has **MAJOR** flaw in that you seem to assume it'll be called **once per row** - that is **not** the case. The trigger will fire **once per statement**, so if your `UPDATE` statements affects 25 rows, you'll get the trigger fired **once**, but then `Inserted` and `Deleted` will each contain 25 rows. Which of those 25 rows will your code select here?? `select @CompanyName=i.CompanyName from inserted i;` - it's non-deterministic - one will be picked, all others ignored. You need to rewrite your trigger to take this into account!

Comment: Thanks @marc_s can you suggest changes to my code?

Comment: Besides the problem of set operation metioned by marc_s, what would the expected Audit_Action be if more then one field is updated e.g. CityName and  Address and ...?

Answer (score 3):

Basically, you need to rework your trigger to be able to handle **multiple rows** in the `Inserted` (and `Deleted`) pseudo table - your trigger gets called only once, even if an `UPDATE` statement affects 10, 20, 50 rows.

So basically, your code needs to look something like this:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[Trigger_UpdateLeadMasters] 
ON [dbo].[LeadMasters]
FOR UPDATE
AS
    INSERT INTO dbo.LoggerLeadMasters(CompanyName, PersonName, Designation, Number, Number2, 
                                      EmailAddress, Address, Address2, CityName, State, 
                                      PinNumber, Product, RemarkNote, 
                                      Audit_Action, Audit_Timestamp)
       SELECT
          CompanyName, PersonName, Designation, Number, Number2, 
          EmailAddress, Address, Address2, CityName, State, 
          PinNumber, Product, RemarkNote, 
          '?????', GETDATE()
       FROM
          Inserted
```

Now the big challenge is going to be to come up with that `Audit_Action`, since you now potentially inserted several rows, each of which might have different columns that were updated....

Typically, you can't just convert this to a single string - what one normally does is to store the old and new columns of interest - and thus you always have the information of what was updated available later on.

Also: SQL Server **2008** and newer have a lot of this functionality already built-in - it's called **Change Data Capture** and this could potentially save you from having to write dozens of triggers - check it out!

Comment: marc_c Thanks for replying.I have tried CDC but I couldn't figure out where the modified column values are stored.The main aim here is to track the modifications and show it on a DataGridView.